# Facebook share button - Canonical URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Prob, some tricks with FB OG tags..

I can share a page via FB:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://some.url" />
```

When user shared the page, and other user clicks to the post from the FB, he will be redirected to the http://some.url.

so, the question is (and it is very interesting for me), can I send (or pass or change or something else) URL, that if user clicks to the post, he will be redirected to the http://some_new.url (not to the http://some.url) ?

and, of course, I want to use OG tags (like title, description, image, etc.) from the webpage where the first user shared the post - http://some.url. :) - <strike>what? what do you want, the stupid man ?!</strike>

Prob, it is impossible, I couldn't find any information about change/replace canonical URL.

Very interesting your opinions, guys.

and, of course, thanks ,)

Comment: Facebook will always request the OG meta data from the address specified as `og:url` or canonical URL. You can however redirect human visitors arriving at that URL to somewhere else – either client-side per JS (which the FB scraper doesn’t care about), or server-side (then you’ll need to add an exception for the FB scraper, which can be recognized by its User-Agent.)

Comment: All right, as you mentioned, FB will grab OG tags, from the last url, in this case I can't use OG tags from the first page. I thought, about JS redirect, but it looks like _old_ style :)

Comment: I did some research, and I believe, JS redirect one possible solution.